# How can I get devise errors for a sign in form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise

I'll preface this by saying that I have read the duplicate questions. They seem to be pretty old, and their solutions have not worked.

I have the following code for a custom sign in form in `views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_with model: resource, url: session_path(resource_name), as: resource_name do |form| %>
    <%= form.text_field :email, class: "input" %>
    <%= form.password_field :password, class: "input" %>
    <%= tag.button(class: "btn-gradient input-button", type: "submit") do %>
        <span>Sign In</span>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I am trying to pull errors and display them, and the following does *not* work:

```
<% if resource.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error">
        <% resource.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            - <%= message %></br>
        <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

I've tried a few other variants online, but it does not seem that any errors are caught. If I type an incorrect email password combination, nothing happens. I've used the same syntax in other forms (like creating or editing a model), and it works fine.

Not sure why it's different with a devise sign in.

How can I get errors in a devise form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your expectations are wrong.

The speedrun explaination of how authentication in Devise works is that `Devise::SessionsController#create` calls `self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)` and if Warden cannot find a user with the given email/password it will [throw(:warden)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/catch-and-throw-exception-in-ruby/). The throw is then caught by calling `Devise::FailureApp` which redirects the user to the sign in path.

This is a more complex operation then your average scaffolded Rails controller that just renders the new view when the validations fail.

There are no errors on the `resource` object because:

- `resource` in your form is not the same instance as when authentication was performed in a completely different request cycle.
- There were no errors added in the first place because this isn't the case of simple validations failing. Nor should there be.

### You Ain't Gonna Need It.

When Devise performs validation it fails it just sets a flash message which by default is `"Invalid email or password."`. Remember that flash messages are passed through a cookie from one request to the next - model instances are not.

This is also the only feedback you should actually give. If you for example added a separate "Invalid email" message it lets an attacker performing a brute force attack determine if an email exists and you just made thier job a whole lot easier.

You can customize the flash messages simply by [defining your own locale file](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/451ff6d49c71e543962d2b29d77f2e744b2d47e1/config/locales/en.yml) and if you want to you can display the flash messages on the form.